# Choose C++ template at runtime

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to achieve the functionality of below code without creating the mapping between strings and classes manually?

```
template<class base, typename T>
base* f(const std::string &type, T &c) {

    if(type == "ClassA") return new ClassA(c);
    else if(type == "ClassB") return new ClassB(c);
    // many more else if...

    return nullptr;
}
```

All classes looks something like this:

```
class ClassA: public BaseClass {
public:
    std::string label="ClassA";
    ...

};
```

And we can use it as:

```
BaseClass *b = f<BaseClass>("ClassA", DifferentObject);
```

Each new class results in a new `if else` line of code. Is there any way to automate this so `f` function "updates" itself when new supported class is added? The solution must work for C++11.

Comment: Short answer: No. You can use macros to automate parts of it. Further, you could use an enum instead of a string and use a switch to make the code a bit tidier.

Comment: Is the string only known at run-time? Otherwise, `f<ClassA>` seems better.

Comment: If the class name and the string are equal, then you could create a macro, that do the mapping. It's only replaces the if...else structure, but needs a recompilation if a new class is added. Is it acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes, string is known at runtime. @n314159 can you please post an example macro. Thanks.

Comment: @zerocukor287 Yes this sounds good to me, but i don;t know how to write such a macro

Comment: Also, this could be interesting, however I have no clue how to use it to this purpose. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile-time_function_execution

Comment: @Elliott Just to clarify, the function string argument is only known at runtime.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Please use the abtract factory pattern. I will post a solution below, but unfortunately it is not C++ 11 compatble. But you may get an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible macro:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class BaseClass {};
class ClassA : public BaseClass {
  public:
    std::string label = "ClassA";
    explicit ClassA(int /*unused*/) {}
};
class ClassB : public BaseClass {
  public:
    std::string label = "ClassB";
    explicit ClassB(int /*unused*/) {}
};
template<class base, typename T>
auto f(const std::string &type, T c) -> std::unique_ptr<base> {
#define CASE(NAME)                                                                                                     \
    if (type == "NAME") {                                                                                              \
        return std::unique_ptr<base>(new NAME(c));                                                                     \
    }
    CASE(ClassA)
    CASE(ClassB)
//...
#undef CASE
    return nullptr;  // Statement at the end needed for last else!
}
auto main() -> int {
    auto b = f<BaseClass>("ClassA", 0);
}
```

Also use `unique_ptr` since memory managing raw pointers are EVIL.

Comment: Thank for this. It still requires changing f function when new class is introduced. Is there any way to automate it further? Somehow find all derived classes of the base class?

Comment: No, that is plainly impossible since new derived classes can be defined anywhere, even in completely unrelated translation units that couldn't possibly change f.

Answer (score 2):

In that case if the class name is equal to the string, you can simplify your code with the following macro:

```
#define STRING_TO_CLASS (className) if(type == "className") return new className(c);

template<class base, typename T>
base* f(const std::string &type, T &c) {

    STRING_TO_CLASS(ClassA)
    STRING_TO_CLASS(ClassB)

    return nullptr;
}
```

Personally I hate macros, but it disturbs only me. However, at compile time, the following code wil be generated, after the macros are resolved.

```
template<class base, typename T>
base* f(const std::string &type, T &c) {

    if(type == "ClassA") return new ClassA(c);
    if(type == "ClassB") return new ClassB(c);

    return nullptr;
}
```

As you see, in the end only the `else` keyword is removed. Also, you need to modify your code if a new class is added.

Comment: Thanks for that. This macro makes life a little easier but still "registration" of classes I would describe as manual.

Comment: You don't want "automatic" registration. Somebody could pass `std::ofstream` and start overwriting files!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the registry pattern like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

template< typename T, typename X >
using Factory = std::function< T* ( X& ) >;


template< typename Base, typename X >
struct Registry {

    using Map = std::map<std::string,Factory<Base,X> >;
    static Map registry;

    template< typename T >
    struct Register {
        Register( const std::string& name ) {
            registry[ name ] = []( X& x ) -> T* { return new T(x); };
        }
    };
};

template< typename Base, typename X >
Base* factory(const std::string &type, X &c ) {
    auto it = Registry<Base,X>::registry.find( type );
    if ( it!=Registry<Base,X>::registry.end() ) {
        return (it->second)(c);
    }
    return nullptr;
}

struct X {};

struct A {
    A( X& x ) {};
    virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : public A {
    B( X& x ) : A(x) {};
};

struct C : public A {
    C( X& x ) : A(x) {};
};

struct D : public B {
    D( X& x ) : B(x) {};
};



// Register class
template<> Registry<A,X>::Map Registry<A,X>::registry{};
Registry<A,X>::Register<B> regB( "B" );
Registry<A,X>::Register<C> regC( "C" );
Registry<A,X>::Register<D> regD( "D" );

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    X x;
    A* ptr = factory<A,X>( "B", x );
    B* bptr = dynamic_cast<B*>( ptr );
    if ( bptr!= nullptr ) {
        std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Failed!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct pattern to use here is the "Abstract Factory" pattern.

Maybe you can look it up.

To give you and idea (and not more), what is possible,  I will show you the below code, which even accepts constructors with different signature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Define the factory with an initializer list
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };

    // Add a new entry for the factory
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```